# Hide tab on custom form switching select values

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, uicomponent, forms

I'm working on building a custom form where i need to show and hide other tabs of other form based on a select Value,
[image]

So pretty much i want, when switching on the second value to hide the second tab on the Left,
How can i do it, there's the part of the form Element that i'm working on:

```
<field name="season" sortOrder="40" formElement="select">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">box</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Season</label>
            <dataScope>season</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options>
                        <option name="1" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Estate</item>
                        </option>
                        <option name="2" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Inverno</item>
                        </option>
                        <option name="3" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Sempreverde</item>
                        </option>
                    </options>
                    <caption translate="true">-- Please Select --</caption>
                    <component>Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</component>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

I was just guessing that i need to create custom component for the field so that can call a js file to change dinamically the Hide/show of the tabs, anyone have any clues?